# Django Add methods to all models

Tags: django

I'm creating multiple Django apps. I want to add to every model a function, `exist`. Can I add this function to the built-in model or do I have to use a proxy model?

Answer (score 0):

if you use proxy you will need to create an class proxy per model in your app.  this is no good idea.

[how to use proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

you should use Abstract class.

```
BaseClass(models.Model):
    #here fields option 
    def do_something(self):
        print('Im cool')         

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

SimpleClass(BaseClass):
    # here yours fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = False 

AnotherClass(BaseClass):
    # here yours fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = False

simple = SimpleClass()

simple.do_something() #it will print out 'im cool'

another = AnotherClass()

another.do_something() #it will print out 'im cool'
```

[if you want more information about abstract class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)